# PermissionError: [WinError 32]. Process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a function to deal with power flow,but it cannot process well becaus of the PermissionError: [WinError 32]. Body of the function follows:

```
ckp = copy.deepcopy(r1)
bc1 , nc1 , gc1 = copy.deepcopy(b) , copy.deepcopy(n) , copy.deepcopy(g)         #函数内部变量
#恢复路径上节点参数 
if os.path.exists(r'e:\results\rspathcheck.py'):
    (open(r'e:\results\rspathcheck.py')).close()
    os.remove(r'e:\results\rspathcheck.py')
suc = []
for pt in pathwt:
    bc1 , nc1 , gc1 = copy.deepcopy(b) , copy.deepcopy(n) , copy.deepcopy(g)         #函数内部变量
    nc1[pt[0],1] = 3        #微网作平衡节点
    nc1[pt[-1],1] = 1       #发电机作为PQ节点
    nc1[pt[-1],2] = 1       #发电机启动有功
    nc1[pt[-1],3] = 1       #发电机启动无功
    sv = open(r'e:\results\rspathcheck.py','w')
    sv.write('\n\n   From   {}   To   {}\n\n'.format(pt[0],pt[-1]))
    sv.close()
    for i in pt:
        nc1[i - 1,1] = 1
        nc1[i - 1,2] = 0        #有功指定为0
        nc1[i - 1,3] = 0        #无功指定为0
#未恢复节点/支路参数
    for j in set(range(1,n.shape[0] + 1)) - set(pt):
        nc1[j - 1,1] = 4
    for i1 in range(b.shape[0]):
        if bc1[i1,0] not in pt or bc1[i1,1] not in pt:
            bc1[i1,10] = 0
    gc1[pt[-1]- 30,7] = gc1[pt[0] - 30,7] = 1       #发电机状态
    for i2 in pt[1:-1]:
        gc1[i2 - 30,7] = 0 
    gc1[0,7] = 1
    ckp['bus'] = nc1
    ckp['branch'] = bc1
    ckp['gen'] = gc1
    rspathcheck = runpf(ckp,slovedcase = r'e:\results\rspathcheck.py')
    #(open(r'e:\results\rspathcheck.py')).close()
    suc.append(rspathcheck[-1]['succsee'])
(open(r'e:\results\rspathcheck.py')).close()
```

***And the error is:***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-7a0e9e787cd1>", line 3, in <module>
    os.remove(r'e:\results\rspathcheck.py')

PermissionError: [WinError 32]  Process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.:      'e:\\results\\rspathcheck.py'
```

I would appreciate if anyone could help me fix the problem.

Comment: Well, apparently you have `rspatchcheck.py` opened, which forbids you from removing the file. You can only remove it, if it is not currently accessed by another instance.

Comment: But I can't find which file or process is occupying the file.The file only exists in this piece of code not the other. Could you so kind to find which part of this code is accessing 'rspatchcheck.py'?

Comment: There's already a good answer, so I just want to comment on general quality code. Please, do not write such a bad code. Never used one-two letter variable names like `b`, `nc1`, `gc1`. Such code is extremely hard to understand and modify. Even you yourself won't be able to understand what this snippet of code does after one month.